Bone heat weighting



I have a problem, i cant parent my mesh with bones, because the outcome is that mesh doesnt move with bones in pose mode. I'am guessing its because of the hair ive created but, i dont know how to fix it. Ive tried bevel, putting the hairs inside of mesh, changing scale etc.
